# How to set notification system in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a notification system with Django. I have an approval process in my project. A user approves a document according to his/her role. For example manager sent a document to the regional manager and wait for the approval. When the manager sends the document it goes to the regional manager's pending approvals list.

I created these tables. What I want to is When the user's pending approval is found, write it in the notification icon above. How can I do it?

*Note:* The notification bar in base.html

There is a picture for understanding clearly.
[image: explanation]

**views.py**

```
def approval(request):
    current_user = request.user
    rank_priority = RankPriority.objects.filter(rank = current_user.rank)
    priority = rank_priority[0].priority
    pend_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(status = priority )
    submit_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id = current_user)

    context = {
        'pend_list': pend_list,
        'submit_list': submit_list
    }
    return render(request, 'approvals.html', context)
```

**approvals.html**

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="page-inner">
      <div class="page-header">
         <h4 class="page-title">Approvals</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-secondary" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Pending Approvals</a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Submitted Approvals</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="tab-content mt-2 mb-3" id="pills-tabContent">
                     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
                           <div class="card">
                              <div class="card-title">Pending Approvals</div>
                              <div class="card-body">
                                 <table class="table table-head-bg-primary mt-4">
                                    <thead>
                                       <tr>
                                          <th scope="col">#</th>
                                          <th scope="col">User</th>
                                          <th scope="col">Document ID</th>
                                          <th scope="col">Beginning Date</th>
                                          <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                                          <th scope="col">Approve</th>
                                       </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    {% for pend in pend_list %}
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>1</td>
                                       <td>{{ pend.last_approved.username }}</td>
                                       <td><a href="{% url 'ocr' id=pend.doc_id.id%}">{{ pend.doc_id }}</a></td>
                                       <td>{{ pend.begin_date }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ pend.end_date }}</td>
                                        <td><a href="{% url 'approvals:approve_pending' pk=pend.pk%}">Approve</a></td>

                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
                        <div class="card">
                           <div class="card-title">Submitted Approvals</div>
                           <div class="card-body">
                              <table class="table table-head-bg-primary mt-4">
                                 <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                       <th scope="col">#</th>
                                       <th scope="col">User</th>
                                       <th scope="col">Document ID</th>
                                       <th scope="col">Beginning Date</th>
                                       <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                                       <th scope="col">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>
                                    {% for submit in submit_list %}
                                    <tr>
                                       <td>1</td>
                                       <td>{{ submit.last_approved.username }}</td>
                                       <td><a href="{% url 'ocr' id=submit.doc_id.id%}">{{ submit.doc_id }}</a></td>
                                       <td>{{ submit.begin_date }}</td>
                                       <td>{{ submit.end_date }}</td>
                                        {% if submit.status > submit.highest_rank %}
                                            <td>Approved</td>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <td>Waiting</td>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </tr>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                 </tbody>
                              </table>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to [create and register your custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). For each request, your own template context processor will recalculate the state of notifications.

```py
def approval_context_processor(request):
    current_user = request.user
    rank_priority = RankPriority.objects.filter(rank = current_user.rank)
    priority = rank_priority[0].priority
    pend_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(status = priority )
    submit_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id = current_user)

    context = {
        'pend_list': pend_list,
        'submit_list': submit_list
    }

    return context
```

On your settings:

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        '# ...,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #...,
                'approval_context_processor',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

At this point, `pend_list` and `submit_list` will be available on all templates.